# CSS files throwing error in server side JSX

Tags: css, reactjs, express, jsx, viewengine

I am using express on the server and using jsx as the view engine. When I try to import CSS files in my jsx file
`import './style.css'` the page throws an error on the first line

```
#container{
^^
Unexpected identifier
```

Even if I use other css files, for eg.
`import antd\dist\antd.css` it throws the same error. Please tell me if I should add any more details. Please help.

Edit: Someone told me that I need to configure style-loader because I am not using webpack or create-react-app but using jsx as a view engine. Any suggestions or steps on how to do that would be appreciated. I have already npm installed style-loader and css-loader

Comment: Are you using docker?

Comment: what is `#container:`? something like that is a syntax error.

Comment: @Muhammad Ali No, I am not using docker.

Comment: @ciekals it's an id and it's `#container{` I made a mistake earlier. But I don't think the error is in Css as every css file I tried gives the same error.